# F#: Converting tuples into a hashtable

Tags: f#, hashmap, hashtable

I am new to programming, and this is my first time working with a typed, functional, and .NET language, so pardon me if my question is silly/trivial.

I have a list of tuples, and I would like to store the first item (which is a string) of each tuple as a value in the hashtable, and the second item (which is a byte array) of each tuple as a key. How may I go about doing so?

Here is my code:

```
let readAllBytes (tupleOfFileLengthsAndFiles) =
    let hashtable = new Hashtable()
    tupleOfFileLengthsAndFiles
    |> snd
    |> List.map (fun eachFile -> (eachFile, File.ReadAllBytes eachFile))
    |> hashtable.Add(snd eachTuple, fst eachTuple)
```

However, the last line is underscored in red. How can I improve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easies way is to use `dict`

It will convert a sequence of tuples in a Dictionary which is a string type Hashtable.

```
> dict [(1,"one"); (2,"two"); ] ;;
val it : System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int,string> =
  seq [[1, one] {Key = 1;
             Value = "one";}; [2, two] {Key = 2;
                                        Value = "two";}]
```

If you are really interested in a Hashtable you can use this simple function:

```
let convert x = 
  let d = Hashtable()
  x |> Seq.iter d.Add
  d
```

So, I'm not sure what do you want to do with this, it seems you're also interested in reading the file in the middle of the conversion. May be something like this:

```
let readAllBytes (tupleOfFileLengthsAndFiles:seq<'a*'b>) =
    tupleOfFileLengthsAndFiles
        |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> x, File.ReadAllBytes y)
        |> convert
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added a code sample to my question. Would you kindly read through it and let me know what modifications I have to make if I still want to use a hashtable? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Gustavo. That was very useful.

I have a follow-up question: Now I want to filter out all the keys that have <1 values. How may I do so?

Comment: @MY_G Just insert `|> Seq.filter (fun (x, _) -> x >= 1)` in the pipeline.

Comment: Hello Gustavo, thanks for your help. I did as you suggested, but received the following error message: "error FS0001: The type 'unit' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'"

Comment: @MY_G Where did you insert that line? It should be for example between the `|> Seq.map .. `line and the `|> convert .. ` line.